# Can computers find zeros of order $2$?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, na.numerical-analysis, computer-science, proof-assistants

We assume we are given an entire function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ with $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=0$ and $f$ is real on the real axis.

We assume (as a fact about $f$, that we want to demonstrate computationally using other facts about $f$) that $f$ has a zero of order $2$ at some real $z_0 \in \mathbb R$ and that there is no other zero of $f$ inside the disc of radius $2\vert z_0 \vert$ apart from this one.

We assume we have access to the Taylor expansion of $f$ and any of its derivatives, i.e. we have access to coefficients $a_k(n)$

$$f^{(n)}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^N a_k(n) z^k + R_{N,n}(z),$$
where we also have a bound on $\lvert R_{N,n}(z)\rvert$ for any $z,N,n.$

The task is now: Given $\varepsilon>0$, is it possible to show with the help of a computer that there exists $z_0^* \in \mathbb R$ with $\lvert z_0^*-z_0 \rvert \le \varepsilon$ such that $f$ has a zero of order $2$ at $z_0^*$? Does there exist an algorithmic way for a computer to show this?

To see why the order $2$ is subtle here. If one wanted to show the existence of a zero of order $1$ instead, this would be trivial as it would suffice to show that $f$ changes sign and $f'$ is non-zero in a neighbourhood of where the sign change happens.

Comment: What does "changes sign" mean of a complex-valued function?  Real or complex part, I guess?

Comment: @LSpice The OP specifies that $f$ is real on the real axis.

Comment: The argument principle may be useful here since $f$ has no poles, though I don't know if there's a way to distinguish between two very close simple zeroes and a single isolated double zero.

Comment: @doobdood In a similar direction I thought about studying $f/f'.$ This function has only a zero of order 1 in a vicinity of our point of interest. By studying $f''$ we know the root cannot be of order higher than $2$. Hence, the question is only whether $f$ has a simple zero at this point or a zero of order $2$. If it was a simple zero, this would imply that $f$ takes negative values, on the real line, after passing through the zero which one can rule out by the Taylor series of $f$. The problem with this is $f/f'$ is not a nice function (it has a pole at 0) so I don't know how to bound it.

Comment: Apply Newton's method to find the zeros in the disc, then check to see the derivative is zero there as well.  This would appear to be computable-enough for your formalism, but perhaps you have problems with this?

Comment: @RyanBudney As I understand it, the OP wants a proof that the function really has a zero, not just an algorithm that can show that the function can get arbitrarily close to zero. But I admit that I don't quite understand "We assume (as a fact we want to prove)" since if we allow ourselves to assume X then (under one interpretation) there is a trivial proof of X: just cite the axiom.

Comment: If the pole of $f/f'$ at zero is your only problem, use $xf/f'$.

Comment: @TimothyChow: There's the Kantorovich theorem that allows you to certify zeros using Newton's method.  I clearly don't understand what the question-asker is looking for.

Comment: When my students "assume a fact that we want to prove" I give them 0 points. What do you mean by that?

Comment: That disc of radius $2 |z_0|$, where is its center, at the origin?

Comment: @AndrejBauer When Pritam Bemis said "prove" I took that to mean "computationally verify".

Comment: @PaceNielsen: See my answer, I think we are in agreement.

Comment: @PritamBemis: it would help if you made your question technically more precise. In the title you speak of "finding zeroes", but in the text of "showing that there exists". Which is it, those are not the same thing? It would help if we (or at least I) knew how much background you have in computable analysis and computability theory on reals. It's a tricky subject that should not be approached naively, because that just causes confusion (the present discussions confirm this).

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure I understand exactly how the Taylor expansion of $f(z)$ is "given," but suppose it is "given" only in the sense that for any specified $n$, I can consult an oracle that will tell me the coefficient of $z^n$. Then there is no way I can rule out the possibility that the "given" function is actually $g(z) := f(z) + \delta z^{2N}$ for unknown large $N$ and unknown small $\delta$ (if $f$ is positive in the vicinity of $z_0$ then take $\delta>0$; if it is negative then take $\delta<0$).  Without knowing $N$ and $\delta$, we do not know how far out to search the coefficients or how good our bounds need to be.  Since $f$ has a zero of order 2 at $z_0$ but $g$ does not, we cannot tell whether the given function has a zero of order 2.

Comment: To extend on this: In any standard model of computation you can only ever know finitely many Taylor coefficients up to finite precision. This only allows you to characterize your function up to small perturbations. So the only thing you can ever deduce on your function are properties stable under small perturbations. Single real zeros are stable, double real zeros aren't: If you perturb your function, they can either turn into two real zeros arbitrarily close to each other, or two complex zeros arbitrarily close to each other (and no real ones).

Comment: Nicely explained. This issue comes up in connection with the question of determining whether a numerically computed zero of the Riemann zeta function is a double zero or two distinct zeros that are very close to each other. As far as I understand there is no known algorithm that’s guaranteed to certify a double zero in finite time. See [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7783/proving-a-known-zero-of-the-riemann-zeta-has-real-part-exactly-1-2) that touches briefly on this point.

Comment: The OP says you get estimated on the remainders of the Taylor series, and that matters.

Comment: @AndrejBauer It seems to me that Timothy Chow's answer shows that estimates on the remainder also cannot solve this problem; by taking $\delta$ as small as we want, we can make the remainder as small as we want.

Comment: @AndrejBauer In fact, at one point, I deleted my answer because I thought that the remainder estimate might save us, but as David Speyer says, if we don't know how small $\delta$ is then we don't know how good an estimate we need to terminate.

Comment: I just gave a very general argument for establishing the fact that *all* predicates on the space given by the OP are constant. I hope it holds water.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an incidental remark, but perhaps with interesting substance: if we run a numerical Newton-Raphson process to approximate an alleged double $0$, at some point it will behave very badly, [EDIT: if there is no actual zero...] throwing the "next approximation" far away. I've never thought about quantifying this...

Comment: Good point. It doesn't solve the problem under discussion, though, because you can't rule out the possibility that the bad behavior was just about to start, except that you prematurely decided to halt your computation.

Answer (score 1):

I find the question written in a confusing way, so I am not sure I understood it correctly, but perhaps the following observation can help.

In order to pose the question correctly, we need to work in a setup that endows mathematical structures with computability, of which there are several. I am going to work with computability over (Type 1) Turing machines, in which every structure is endowed with a Gödel coding that provides a notion of computability.

Throughout all entities are therefore going to be computable. I am not going to keep writing that. Nontheless, when we write down a function, we must argue that it is computable.

Let
$$
S = \{ f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \mid
\text{$f$ entire, $f(0) = 1$, $f'(0) = 0$, $f(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$} 
\}.
$$
(Note that according to the above statement, $S$ contains only computable maps. Moreover, the elements of $f$ are *computably* entire, which implies that all their higher derivatives are also computable.)

The map $u : [0,1] \times S \times S \to S$, defined by
$$
u(f, g, t) = (z \mapsto t \cdot g(z) + (1 - t) \cdot h(z))
$$
is computable. That is, $S$ is a computable convex space, computably so. (One last time, let me note that the elements of $[0,1]$ are the computable reals between $0$ and $1$.)

We claim that every computable predicate $P : S \to \{0, 1\}$ is constant, thereby answering the original question negatively. Indeed, the question was whether a predicate of the form
$$f \mapsto
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $f$ has a certain kind of zero}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is computable.

Suppose first that $P$ is non-constant, i.e., there are (computable) $g, h \in S$ such that $P(g) = 1$ and $P(h) = 0$. Then the map $[0,1] \to \{0, 1\}$, defined by
$$
t \mapsto P(u(g, h, t))
$$
is computable, hence continuous (this is a fundamental theorem in computable analysis) and therefore constant (this holds even when we work just with computable reals). But this cannot be because $P(u(g, h, 0)) = P(h) = 0$ and $P(u(g, h, 1)) = P(h) = 1$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Does your answer address the question?  Let $S$ be as in your post.  If $f\in S$ happens to have a simple zero, then there is a computational procedure that will eventually verify this fact (using approximations for $f$ and $f'$ near such a zero). Thus, the class of such functions is semidecidable.  Your argument shows that this class is not decidable.  Similarly, I think the OP was asking whether or not the class of functions with double zeros is semidecidable (rather than decidable).

Comment: @SamHopkins: fixed, thanks.

Comment: @PaceNielsen: the OP does not seem to know the standard terminology, so we have some guessing to do. It sounded to me like they were asking for a decision procedure that can decide whether a certain predicate (has such-and-such double zero) holds. My answer, if correct, shows that no predicate whatsoever can be computable, unless it's trivial.

Comment: How do you verify that $f$ has zero at $x$? That's not a semidecidable predicate, it's co-semidecidable.

Comment: Andrej, I agree the OP didn't use standard terminology, but I personally thought the OP made it clear what they were asking for, by giving the case of order 1 zeros.  And note, the question isn't asking for us to computationally verify where the zeros are located.  It is asking us to merely verify their order.  The *order*, for order 1 zeros, is computationally semidecidable.  Their *position* is co-semidecidable as you say.

Comment: You did not say "the order of order 1 zeroes is computationally semidecidable", did you? Apart from that being trivial, a *number* cannot be semidecidable. So what is the precise claim you're making? Is it just something that will reduce to verifying that some derivative is non-zero?

Comment: Rephrasing, the OP's question seems to be: Is it semidecidable whether $f\in S$ has a real zero of order $2$? (This involves some issues concerning position, but not to the level of asking that $f$ have a zero at a specified $x\in \mathbb{R}$.) The answer to the OP's question seems to be no, essentially by Timothy's answer.  It is semidecidable that $f'$ has a simple real zero.  However, given $f$ (together with the computation describing a simple real zero of $f'$), it is only co-semidecidable that $f$ has two real roots near that simple real zero of $f'$.

Comment: However, this does raise the interesting question of whether, if we **computably** know that the two zeros of $f$ (near that simple real zero of $f'$) are real, it is decidable whether or not those two zeros are equal.

Comment: I am giving up because I do not understand the specification given in the question.  My brain already refuses to read past "we assume as a fact that we want to prove".